# How to change Angular Material Table row height?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

In my Angular application (styled with Angular Material) I need to show some data using a Material Table.

This table has a sticky header, several rows and a sticky footer.

**By default, rows have a height of 62.5px and I'd like to override this value.**

How can I achieve that?

I have tried overriding the css style for tr / tr.mat-row / tr.mat-header-row etc, without success. I have tried using ::ng-deep too.

Also, my sticky footer row has a 48px height, which i didn't set!! Does anyone know whats happening?

[Table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkfpM.png)

I'm able to edit the footer row css with ::ng-deep, i have set the font-weight to **bold**, but when i set the height attribute nothing happens.

```
::ng-deep tr.mat-footer-row {
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Try overriding the height with `!important` flag

Comment: You can also specify this `import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
// ...
@Component({
    // ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})` on your component this will override styles !

Comment: The solution to `ViewEncapsulation` was to override very specific css using highly specific css selectors in 1) global css or 2) creating separate style files for certain views / styles / elements, importing into every component required (e.g. `styleUrls: [material-table-override.css, component.css]`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try adding it out on your styles.scss.

```
tr.mat-footer-row {
        border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: #px !important;
}
```

Comment: This works! I've had already tried that but i was adding '::ng-deep' to the style, and it wasn't working. Without ::ng-deep, it worked.

Answer (score 12):

To change the height by default (48 px) in mat-table you need to specify a class for every row in the html, for example, when you define the rows:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedCol;" class="table-row"></tr>
```

Then you can override the height, setting in your main css file the class 'table-row' with a specific height, for example:

```
.table-row {
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

We prove this with angular 7 and angular material version 7.3.7.

Regards

Answer (score 9):

On a related point, I had an issue where my mat-table rows were too high, and tried to set the height in CSS to reduce it.

It turned out that the problem was "min-height" had been set on "mat-header-row" and "mat-row" somewhere deep inside material (not in my source code).

The fix was simply:

```
.mat-header-row, .mat-row {
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**With Angular Material 16**

**header**

```
.mat-mdc-table .mdc-data-table__header-row {
  height: 35px;
}
```

**rows**

```
.mat-mdc-table .mdc-data-table__row{
  height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: I find that anything below 65px does not work. Above that it works ok. Not sure why.

Comment: I ended up surrounding it by a smaller div with no overflow to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

With material 5

```
 mat-row.mat-row.ng-star-inserted 
  { height: 32px !important; } 

.mat-row{ min-height: 30px; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also set it in the `mat-row` element in the template to an exact value.

Using `minHeight` is better than `height` because it overrides the default css.

```
<mat-row
    matRipple
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnNames"
    routerLinkActive="highlighted"
    [style.minHeight.px]="100">
</mat-row>
```

**Update for Angular 15 / Material 15:**

They've now [changed the CSS](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/e6536b7119907a772405661d28a25508ad2e1e9b/guides/v15-mdc-migration.md#table) to use `height` instead of `min-height` so `height.px` would be better. I'm still looking for justification, but my guess would be to try to enforce consistency or perhaps it's performance related.

There's also guidance to just use:

```
 .mat-column-name { height: 100px; } // for column 'name'
```

Comment: this works form me, working with angular mat 9. if i wanted to have a variable height according to the content, what should i change? thank you.

Comment: @OJVM you'd probably be ok to just set height to auto. Either in your css or add `[style.height]="'auto'"` in this example. If it isn't working make sure the developer tools for the row are showing 'auto' and make you copy it exactly as I have it here.

Answer (score 1):

It works correctly.

```
tr.mat-footer-row,
tr.mat-row {
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers are correct but if it doesn't work for you, it probably means you have a div or any element inside the table that has a height set to it, and if this height is greater than the row height you won't be able to override it.

Answer (score 1):

my solution:

```
.mat-header-row{
    max-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the height of the table footer in `tr.mat-footer-row`.

```
tr.mat-footer-row {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here is StackBlitz example https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjjjdpjqvvde?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-footer-example.css

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; in my case, the height of the table was too large relative to the number of rows, so setting the height didn't work. When I adjusted the height to be smaller when I had fewer rows, I was able to set the height again.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this on your style.css**

```
  .mat-row{
    height: 10px !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below line in your .css component file

```
td {
  height: 5rem !important;
}
```

and it should work...

Answer (score 0):

With `@angular/material@17` you can do the following:

```scss
:host {
--mat-table-row-item-container-height: 1rem;
}
```

If you want to change the header and footer too then you can do it this way:

```scss
:host {
  --mat-table-header-container-height: 2rem;
  --mat-table-row-item-container-height: 1rem;
  --mat-table-footer-container-height: 1rem;
}
```